# what is wrong with following code

Tags: php

i have this function to find class from any level of directory

```
function _findFile($path, $class) {
        $founded_file = "";
        $dir = scandir($path);
        foreach ($dir as $file) {
            $current_path = $path . $file;
//            echo $current_path . "\n";
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
//                    echo $current_path . "\n";
                if (is_dir($current_path)) {
                    return $this->_findFile($current_path . "/", $class);
                } else if (is_file($current_path) && end(explode(".", $current_path)) === "php") {
                    if (end(explode("/", $current_path)) === ($class . ".php")) {
                        return $current_path;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $founded_file;
    }
```

my directory structure

```
system
  -base
     -core.php
     -exceptions.php
  -database
     -database.php
```

it is not find file in `system >  database`

if you uncomment first comment then you can see that the function is not going in `system >  database` path

please ask if any doubt

Comment: Is this for an autoloader?

Comment: no this is not for autoloader... please see answer below it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `$this->_findFile($current_path . "/", $class)`

```
$file = $this->_findFile($current_path . "/", $class);
if ($file) {
     return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to know [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) and [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/FilterIterator) classes, they'll help you simplify your code a lot:

```
<?php

class FileFilterIterator extends FilterIterator 
{
    private $filename;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $filename)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        return ($this->getInnerIterator()->current()->getFilename() == $this->filename);
    }
}

function _findFile($path, $className)
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
    $files = array();

    foreach (new FileFilterIterator($iterator, "$className.php") as $file) {
        $files[] = $file->getPathname();
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Comment: good to know this but i am not able to understand first 6 lines of code

Comment: There was a formatting issue in my answer, now you should read all the code. It's using PHP object-oriented features. :)